how to filter model by foreignkey in django's admin forms?
I'm using django 3.2
I have those models.
When adding an item to database through django's admin I'd like to be able to after choose the Disciplina (discipline) item, when I'd choose the assunto(subject) the assunto would be filtered by the subjects of the Discipline chosen above. How to do it in pure django (without javascript)?
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Base(models.Model):
    creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Disciplina(Base):
    ORIGEM_CHOICES = [
        ('PT', 'Exame Nacional Português'),
        ('BR', 'ENEM Brasil'),
        ('SUPERIOR', 'Nível Superior'),
    ]

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    origem = models.CharField(max_length=8, choices=ORIGEM_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.get_origem_display()})"

class subject(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='sujects')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} ({self.discipline.name})"

class Question(Base):
    discipline = models.ForeignKey(Discipline, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    suject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    latex_text = models.TextField(blank = True, null=True)  
    math_jax = models.TextField(blank = True, null = True) 
    answer = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    dificulty = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices=[
        ('FACIL', 'Fácil'),
        ('MEDIO', 'Médio'),
        ('DIFICIL', 'Difícil'),
    ])
    image = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    link_image = models.URLField(blank =True, null=True)
    link_bucket = models.URLField(blank = True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.latex_text


admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Disciplina, Assunto, Questao

@admin.register(Discipline)
class DisciplineAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'origem')
    search_fields = ('name',)
    ordering = ('name',)

@admin.register(Subject)
class SubjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'discipline_name')
    search_fields = ('name',)
    ordering = ('name',)

    def discipline_name(self, obj):
        return obj.discipline.name
    discipline_name.short_description = 'Discipline'

@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('discipline_name', 'subject_name', 'latex_text', 'answer', 'dificulty', 'image', 'link_image')
    search_fields = ('latex_text', 'gabarito')
    ordering = ('discipline', 'subject')

    def discipline_name(self, obj):
        return obj.discipline.name
    discipline_name.short_description = 'Discipline'

    def subject_name(self, obj):
        return obj.suject.name
    subject_name.short_description = 'Subject'
    



that's why a sign of a good tone is to name fields in english. reading question just messes up brain for non-speakers of your language. I assume you need a list_filter on admin model.

Sorry. Now its in english.

as I said - try list_filter on admin model. takes in tuple of fields

Hey, @ZwickVitaly. Thanks for the answer. If I'm not wrong, the list_filter enables to  filter by some options when we are looking the items on our database in the admin painel. My problem is when I try to add a new Item. I have a type of question e.g. a Linear Algebra question, so I choose the discipline, when I go to the other field (subject) instead of only show the Linear Algebra subjects it shows all the subjects that are registered.

aw, that will be a pain doing it in django admin, because formsets are formed server-side. you will have to change JS forms to do this (filtering by some sort of attribute or making api\ajax request to server). filtering only by server-side logic is impossible when you are just filling up the form.
